# Can g++ compilers be used to build linux software on macos?

Tags: macos, c++, compile, cross-platform, g++

On windows I am able to develop for linux using WSL2. I ususally use CLion which allows me to switch between msvc and g++ with a flip of a switch. Is it possible to do the same thing on Mac? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

(I only know for sure you can use to create *Windows* software on MacOS via [MXE](https://mxe.cc) using g++... now I'm very curious if someone has made a similar toolchain to target Linux.)

Weak solution: In a pinch, you could install free [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org) and your preferred Linux (with g++) on a virtual machine. Or even Windows+WSL2, but I guess using Linux directly would be more performant.